# Are there any official images of Salarian Warships

Tags: mass-effect

The Mass Effect Wiki confirms that the Salarian's do in fact maintain a small yet technically advanced fleet, including 16 dreadnoughts with stealth capability covertly obtained from both the Normandy and the Normandy SR2. Unfortunately the Wiki does not display any images of these Ships, which greatly disappoints my appreciation of design.

Google Images is not of any use either, as it returns multiple vessel designs which are obviously fan created.
Does anyone either possess or know-of an official image for a Salarian Ship? And if so, can they please either post it as a response, or post a link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes.**

Specifically, this salarian warship appears in *Mass Effect: Foundation* #9:

[image: Salarian warship]

This is a small frigate, not a dreadnought (for reference, both of the *Normandy*s were frigates).  It was used for one of Mordin's STG reconnaissance missions to test the modified genophage virus.

(This actually appears on a double-page panel, but unfortunately the background doesn't really provide many good reference points for the size of the vessel, so I decided not to include it.)